# SQL query to find those customer who have buy all three items ('ring','diamond','brooch')

Tags: sql, relational-division

```
id   item_name  cust_id 
1     Rolex      5        
2     Diamond    33 
3     Hublop     1         
4     Ring       9          
5     Ruby       13 
6     Rolex      33 
7     Hublop     29 
8     Ring       17 
9     Belt       21 
10    Diamond     9       
12    Belt       33
13    Hublop      9                                                                                                                                                           
14    Brooch      9
```

From these table I have to write a query to  find those cust_id who have buy all three 'diamond,brooch,ring'
without using intersection ( IN clause will also not work)

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Comment: And please explain why you have imposed the restrictions you have.

Comment: And show your desired results. I've removed the conflicting RDBMS tags... feel free to add back the correct tag.

Comment: in mysql its possible using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `FIND_IN_SET` but if you have 3 different dbms that's 3 different answers

Comment: Do you need to find the customers that bought **exactly** those three products (so nothing else) or those that bought _at least_ those three products (but could have bought others as well).

Comment: output -  9   (cust_id of that customer who buy all three items i.e Ring ,Diamond, Brooch)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` with a `case` statement for each item to get how many of that item the client has bought, then filter only customers that have bought at least one of each type of product:

```
select cust_id from
(select cust_id,
  sum(case when item_name = 'Diamond' then 1 else 0 end) as cntDiamond,
  sum(case when item_name = 'Brooch' then 1 else 0 end) as cntBrooch,
  sum(case when item_name = 'Ring' then 1 else 0 end) as cntRing
from table_name
group by cust_id) as t
where cntDiamond > 0 and cntBrooch > 0 and cntRing > 0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57ad81b8646cc3b923ec7b6a151dbf26)